# ASP.NET MVC form actions for Service Routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC app. I have been using just the default routing rule. I have a number of views that render forms using code like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ForgotPassword", "Register", FormMethod.Post))
```

This has been working fine. The form action would post to `/myapp/register/forgotpassword` and everything works great.

Now need to add some service endpoints into the same application. So I added some new routes above the default one. The routing setup now looks like:

```
//New rule
RouteTable.Routes.Add(
    new ServiceRoute(
    "api/user", new MyCustomerServiceHostFactory(),
    typeof(UserWebservice)));

//Default rule
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
  );
```

After I added the new rule all my forms broke. Inspecting the HTML, I can see that the form action is `/myapp/api/user?action=ForgotPassword&amp;controller=Register'`, which is totally wrong.

So my question is: how do I route the new service without breaking all my existing forms?

And for bonus points: what the heck is going on here?

Comment: have you tried to change the order of your mappings, put default above service one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using as below,

```
//New rule
RouteTable.Routes.Add(
    new ServiceRoute(
    "UserWebservice", new MyCustomerServiceHostFactory(),
    typeof(UserWebservice)));

//Default rule
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
  );
```

I think changing the code for route add as [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638620/how-to-use-serviceroutes-while-defining-maxreceivedmessagesize-for-non-custom-bi) link should work.
 Also check this blog for creating [Dynamic service routes](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2011/05/09/Using-dynamic-WCF-service-routes.aspx).

Comment: The route in the code sample did not work. However, the Dynamic Service Route you linked to did the trick. Thanks!